# Getting SQS queue attribute via MassTransit

Tags: c#, .net-core, amazon-sqs, masstransit

I'm currently learning SQS/MassTransit and would like to know if there's a way to get queue attributes via MassTransit(such as `ApproximateNumberOfMessages`). I know I can do this with `AmazonSQSClient`'s `GetQueueAttributesRequest`, just wondering if the same can be done with MassTransit.So far googling yielded no results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MassTransit doesn't expose any of these attributes, you'd need to use the transport-specific client libraries.